# Rectrict user to its own page and show their own project

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login script with a admin thats redirected to his own page `dashboardadmin.php`.Then i have a page called `dashboarduser.php`. The users have its own page `dashboarduser.php`. When the user comes to `dashboarduser.php` it should only show their project. Now its showing all of the projects. I have created the `omproject.php` that show the project. So what i want is when user login is should come to `dashboarduser.php` and only show their projct.

`index.php`

```html
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            echo '<p class="error">Error!</p>';
        }
?> 
        <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">                      
          
    <label for="email"> Email:</label> <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
   
            <label for="password">Password: </label> <input type="password" 
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/>
        
   <input type="submit" 
                   value="Login"
                   onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /> 
                   
</form>
```

`process_login.php`

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
 
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.
 
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
 
    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../dashboardadmin.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}

?>
```

sql DB
[image: SQL DB]

members
project
[image]

`dashboarduser.php`

```html
$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  
        //$type= "Content-type:".$row['image_type'];
  //header ($type);
  echo "<form action='omprojekt.php' method='post'><button name='submit'>
            <div> 
                <img src=pic.php?pid=".$row['pid']." width=100px height=100px/>"." ".$row['project_name']."
            
            <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$row['pid']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='project_name' value='".$row['project_name']."'>
            

            </div>
       </button></form>";
        
    }
}
    
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

`omproject.php`

```html
<?php
    
$val = (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['project_name'])) ? 
    "<img src=pic.php?pid={$_POST['pid']} width=100xp height=100xp/> {$_POST['project_name']}" : '';    
    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
echo "$val";
}
   
?>
```

Comment: Your $sql statement will return all entries within the table. You need to set a  WHERE clause that will only return the appropriate data for the user (you haven't supplied the table so I can't give you fieldnames etc)

Comment: I added a picture of the table now. Im really lost have been trying 2 days now without any progress @jeff

Comment: In `project` do you have any reference from `users` table? You need to keep user id as a foreign key in `project` table something like `member_id`. Let me know if you have any field like that?

Comment: There is no link between the users and project

Comment: @deepakb i have added now user_id to project. I got now a answer that seems be like i wanted. But i dont know how to specify loggedinuserid

Comment: You have to store logged in user user_id in session. And then in the query use that as WHERE condition. That's all!

Comment: All sorted out now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a link between your project table and your user table. You'll need to add a column in your project table which refers to the user that owns the project. Let's name that table "user_id" for now. 
After login you should have the id of the user that's logged in. you can use that to get their project. Then to fetch their projects you can use the following sql query:

```
    $sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project WHERE user_id =" . $loggedInUserId;
```

Comment: I almost got it. I added user_id to the project table. I dont understand where $loggedInUserId comes from?

Comment: You don't have it at the moment, i suggest adding the id from the logged in user in your session. add something like `session_start(); $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;` somewhere where you have the id of the user that's logged in (maybe in your login function) then add this line of code to your dashboarduser.php `session_start(); $loggedInUserId = $_SESSION['userId'];`

Comment: All sorted out now. Thanks :)